# What Causes DynamoDB UpdateItem to Giv Fatal Error in Swift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Swift to let my app update an item on DynamoDB. I followed the example https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSiOSSDKTests/AWSDynamoDBTests.m#L244, the "- (void)testUpdateItem" method. My codes are as follows:

```
var dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB()

var hashValue: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
hashValue.S = userID
var updatedValue: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
updatedValue.S = updatedContent

var updateInput: AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput = AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput()
updateInput.tableName = kAWSDynamoDBMoEndpointARNTableName
updateInput.key = ["UserID": hashValue]
var valueUpdate: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate()
valueUpdate.value = updatedValue
valueUpdate.action = AWSDynamoDBAttributeAction.Put
updateInput.attributeUpdates = ["Updated": valueUpdate]
updateInput.returnValues = AWSDynamoDBReturnValue.UpdatedNew

dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).waitUntilFinished()
```

However, as I run the codes, it always returns **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. Looking into the error, I can find it is from **Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.Uint) -> ()** with **Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)**

I didn't use .continueWithBlock or .continueWithSuccessBlock cuz neither helps to catch the error.

Any idea why? THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an instance of `AWSDynamoDB` as follows:

```
let dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()
```

You are using the default `- init` method without any parameter, and it causes `AWSDynamoDB` instance to have no `AWSServiceConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

With the current AWS, found that this worked well for posting the updateItem in Swift.

```
    dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error == nil) {

            log.debug("task.error == nil")

        }

        return nil

    })
```

// instead of

dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).waitUntilFinished()