# Expected declaration error, Swift, .S

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, declaration

I am new to Swift programming and having a little issue following some code in an example I found.

```
let v1    = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue();
v1.S = "20141101"
```

For v1.S line I am getting an "expected declaration" error.

I believe that the S is string but what is the .S meant to do and what is causing the error?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you missed some declarations? `.S` should work. Hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726488/what-causes-dynamodb-updateitem-to-giv-fatal-error-in-swift in the question's code.

Answer (score 0):

*"expected declaration" error* means in many cases that the code must be in the scope of a method or function.